# how to write backspace html in vue js

Tags: vue.js

how to to wire html backspace in vue js in have try code bellow but not working, try template but dont working to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p><span v-html="backspace"></span></p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el:'#app',
            data:{
                backspace:"&larr"
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `v-text` instead of `v-html`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing semi-colon:

```
&larr // missing semi-colon ;
```

You may also use:

```
&#8592;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you would like to display the left arrow HTML character "&laar;", that looks like an arrow pointing backwards.
You simple missed a semicolon (;) at the end of the HTML within your data array.

Here is the updated snipped:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p><span v-html="backspace"></span></p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el:'#app',
            data:{
                backspace:"&larr;"
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```